# Form a given number x using combinations smaller given number

Tags: algorithm

**EDIT**: I used 2,5, and 16 before. But they were just examples. But now I want to generalize for any 3 numbers.

I have a number lets say N. Can this number be formed only using addition of only x1,x2 and x3. We can use the three number any number of time and in any combination.

Can this solved by dynamic programming or is there some other simple method?

Comment: If N=1 then how can you get last with just addition?

Comment: I had an answer, but I need clarification. Can we use each number only once, or multiple times?

Comment: @eigenchris Multiple times

Comment: This could certainly be solved with dynamic programming.  Are you looking for help in implementing the solution or just wondering if DP is the right approach?

Comment: @nintendojunkie I know how to implement it. It is just the variation of coin exchange problem. But I was wondering if you don't want to count how many ways we can get that number, but just that it is possible, can we use something faster than DP?

Comment: I'm not sure you can, since the greedy algorithm doesn't work.  You're basically doing a brute force search.  DP just prevents calculating the same things over again when you find a "poison number" i.e. a number that, once reached, proves you're on the wrong track.  Once you find a correct answer you can return immediately.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [Chicken McNugget Theorem](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/Chicken_McNugget_Theorem) if you only have 2 coprime values. Otherwise, skip to the `Dynamic programming` solution.

After eliminating the `16` as redundant (because it is a power of 2, so just use more twos instead of it), `2` and `5` are coprime, so the largest number that cannot be written as `2a + 5b` is `2*5 - 2 - 5 = 3`. Anything above this can be written.

For the particular case of `2` and `5` the existence of a solution can also be argued like this: obviously even numbers can be written using only the `2`. For odds:

```
2k+1 = (2k - 4) + 5
```

So these can always be written too once they get large enough, by using twos and one `5`.

For 3 or more numbers, see for example [Frobenius Numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem) and [Numerical semigroups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_semigroup).

**Dynamic programming**

Or if you want to stick to the classics, dynamic programming:

```
dp[i] = true if we can reach sum i
dp[0] = true, false for the rest
for i = 0 to query_sum:
  dp[i] = dp[i] or dp[i - input1] or dp[i - input2] or dp[i - input3]
```

Comment: Nice. That's a neat little theorem.

Comment: An interesting approach (and a smiley face for chicken mcnuggets) - but can't answer the question for general values.

Comment: @nintendojunkie - what do you mean general values? It can answer for any coprime pairs.

Comment: Nice solution. But I used the above only as an example. I wanted to generalize for any 3 numbers

Comment: @IVlad Consider the McNuggets problem you linked to.  If you can buy nuggest in 9 or 20 piece packages, then you can create any number of nuggets more than 151.  But the theorem won't tell you whether or not you can create 62 nuggets.

Comment: @nintendojunkie - it will tell you that you only have to brute force / solve / precompute for a constant number of values, which can lead to an `O(1)` algorithm.

Comment: @CompGeek - there is work done for 3 values as well, see for example: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem

Comment: @IVlad Ooh, good point.  It doesn't provide a solution for everything, but there's a lot of numbers between 151 and infinity.

Comment: @CompGeek - I have added generalizations as well.

Comment: @nintendojunkie - everything above 151 **can** be written. You only care about those **below** it.

Comment: @IVlad Now the only question is: how hard is it to determine whether arbitrary numbers are comprime. :)

Comment: @IVlad Yes, that's what I meant.  Your theorem takes care of all of the numbers above 151.

Comment: @nintendojunkie, if the GCD of two numbers is 1, they are coprime. I don't think this is too hard to check?

Comment: The DP-approach for the general is exponential in the size of the input, that sounds like a somewhat inefficient method.

Comment: @G.Bach A hybrid approach could be useful here.  Calculate the McNugget number, and if N is smaller than that, use DP.

Comment: @nintendojunkie - McNugget won't work for 3 numbers. You'd need to use  the Frobenius formula, which is harder because it's not exact, but decent bounds seem to be known.

Comment: And that is still assuming the 3 numbers are coprime. I think DP works best in the general case.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to solve a [linear diophantine equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation#System_of_linear_Diophantine_equations), basically checking whether a linear system has integer solutions. Your linear system would be

```
a*2 + b*5 + c*16 = N
```

and you're looking for `(a,b,c)`. Apparently, solving this involves a bit of playing around with matrices in certain normal forms.

Comment: +1 for interesting.  Unfortunately it's probably a lot less work to use brute force than to solve the linear system.

Comment: Do you mean from an implementation or from a complexity point of view? For a single equation, the matrix shenanigans should be pretty straightforward and efficient.

Comment: Implementation.  The computational complexity would certainly be superior using the linear system (for large N).